# Stuck creating a formula in crystalreports

Tags: function, layout, syntax, crystal-reports, formula

I'm a bit stuck trying to create a formula in crystal reports, hope you guys can give me some input. To the question, I need to come up with a formula for the 'price' on a receipt. The price column is supposed to show the price for a single item, in other words if the receipt shows a quantity of 4x something that costs 5 dollar the price column will show 5 dollar and not 20 ( the value I'm getting right now)

The hard part for me is that quantity is being inserted as a string and I can't divide the quantity number of the string cause of the postfix to get the sum, think there must be some way to exclude the text and just get the value position.

The formulas that I'm working with right now.

Amount/quantity -- antall

```
If Ubound(Split({AccountNoticeDet.Description}, ";"))>0
Then
left({AccountNoticeDet.Description}, (instr({AccountNoticeDet.Description}, 
";") + 3))
Else ""
```

Antalltonumber

```
tonumber({@antall})
```

Unitpriceinclvat - The formula that is supposed to show the single amount price on the receipt.

```
{AccountNoticeDet.Amount}/{@antalltonumber}
```

Comment: provide more info on where have you placed the formulas in crystal report and where exactly you want to show the calculation, Also how does the formula `antall` output looks?

Comment: so which one is not working? basically you are just after of the unit amount.... a simple division should just solve your issue